# How to get the dataset value in table using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, alert

I was trying to get the label and data value from the following

```
var barChartData = {
  labels: Months,
  datasets: [{
    label: 'Dataset 1',
    backgroundColor: "#09a",
    data: [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35]
  }]
};
```

I tried using `alert(JSON.stringify(barChartData.datasets.data));`  but I got output as undefined. Please help me to find out this .

Comment: try this `alert(JSON.stringify(barChartData.datasets[0].data))`

Answer (score 0):

Like Sachin K wrote in the comment.

You forget that datasets is an array **containing** an object.

Therefor you need

```
alert(JSON.stringify(barChartData.datasets[0].data))
```

With the [0] you specify that you want the value from the first element in the array (array's are zero based)

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach..

```js
var barChartData = {
  labels: 'Months',
  datasets: [{
    label: 'Dataset 1',
    backgroundColor: "#09a",
    data: [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35]
  }]

};

//For multiple dataset

var data = []; label = [];
barChartData.datasets.map(function(dt) {
  data.push(dt.data);
  label.push(dt.label);
})

//Single datasets

var data1 = barChartData.datasets[0].data;
var label1 = barChartData.datasets[0].label;

console.log(data, label, data1, label1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```